# Mod mail command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Someone know how to make the bot close the modmail? Like the member start spamming on the bot dms and you want to like block him

here is my modmail code

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
channel = client.get_channel(909853337510371449)
if message.author.id == client.user.id:
return

```
if message.author != message.author.bot:
    if not message.guild:
        await channel.send(f"[{message.author.mention}] {message.content}")
        

await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: You could store the blocked user IDs in a json file or similar and in your code check if the message author id is in that.

Comment: you can make a timeout, so if the bot hasnt seen a message in like a minute it closes